# Using an item in an array in a condition statement

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of modals in my redux store that looks like this:

```
modals: [
        {id: "modal1", isDisplayed: false},
        {id: "modal2", isDisplayed: true}
    ]
```

In my React component, I want to have simple condition statements to display or not display my modals. I'm having a bit of trouble setting my condition statements right.

```
{this.props.modals["modal1"].isDisplayed ? <Modal1 /> : null}
{this.props.modals["modal2"].isDisplayed ? <Modal2 /> : null}
```

What's the right syntax to check the isDisplayed property of a given modal in my modals array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `modals` property in the store is an `Array`. You can't access it by `id`.

This code will work:

```
{ this.props.modals[0].isDisplayed && <Modal1 /> }
{ this.props.modals[1].isDisplayed && <Modal2 /> }
```

Alternatively you can store it in the following way:

```
modals: {
  modal1: { isDisplayed: false },
  modal2: { isDisplayed: true },
}
```

Then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), however it can't be inlined well in an expression without null coalescing operator.

This would break when a modal is not found (when `find` returns `undefined`)

```
{ this.props.modals.find(x => x.id === "nonexistingmodal").isDisplayed && <ModalXYZ /> }
```

With a little helper function you can implement it safely with minor code changes:

```
const select = (from, selector) => from && selector(from)

{ select(this.props.modals.find(x => x.id === "modal3"), x => x.isDisplayed) && <Modal3 /> }
```

You should consider using a `Map` or just a plain object as a modal store in order to express key relationships.